# Crear un objeto en el controlador desde un formulario y pasárselo al modelo MVC PHP

Tags: php, mysql, poo, mvc

tengo un formulario donde relleno unos datos de usuario, luego al aceptar me manda al controlador donde tengo que crear un objeto candidato con los datos recibidos para después mandarle ese objeto a una función en el modelo para que haga un insert.
Este es el formulario:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href=\"miestilo.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />

<title>Formulario para añadir datos </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<center><h2>Formulario de altas<h2></center> 

<form name="altas" method="POST" action="grabar.php"> 
<table bgcolor="#E9FFFF" align=center border=2> 

<td align="right">Escribe tu D.N.I.: </td> 
<td align="left"> <input type="text" name="dni" value="" size=8></td><tr> 
<td align="right">Nombre....: </td> 
<td align="left"> <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" size=20></td><tr> 
<td align="right">Apellidos...: </td> 
<td align="left"> <input type="text" name="apellidos" value="" size=15></td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td align="right">Sexo...:</td> 
<td align="left"> 
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="m"  > Masculino 
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="f" > Femenino 
</td>

</select> </tr><tr> 

       


<td align="right">Habla:<br> 
(<i>Si habla varios seleccionarlos<br> 
pulsando con el mouse encima de <br> 
cada uno de ellos con la tecla<br> 
<b>Ctrl</b> presionada</i>)</td> 
<td align="left"> <SELECT MULTIPLE name="idiomas[]" SIZE=9> 

<?php
         foreach($arrayIdiomasPersonas as $idioma)
         {
            echo "<option value='".$idioma["id"]."'>".$idioma["nombre"]."</option>";
         }
         ?>

</select> 
</td><tr> 
    


<!--colocamos los botones de enviar y borrar //--> 


<td align=center><input type=submit name="accion" value="Enviar"></td> 
<td align=center><input type=submit name="accion" value="Cancelar"></td> 
</table> </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Y esta la función que tengo en el modelo:

```
public static function insertDatos($candidatoNuevo)
{
   //recibe un objeto candidato e inserta los datos en la tabla
}
```

Y esta la clase Candidato:

```
<?php

class Candidato {
    protected $dni;
    protected $nombre;
    protected $apellidos;
    protected $sexo;
    protected $idiomas;//array de idiomas
      
    public function getDni() {return $this->dni; }
    public function getNombre() {return $this->nombre;}
    public function getApellidos() {return $this->apellidos;}
    public function getSexo() {return $this->sexo;}
    public function getIdiomas() {return $this->idiomas;}

    public function __construct($pdni,$pnombre,$papellidos,$psexo,$pidiomas) 
    {
        $this->dni = $pdni;
        $this->nombre = $pnombre;
        $this->apellidos=$papellidos;
        $this->sexo=$psexo;
        $this->idiomas=$pidiomas;                       
    }
    

}

?>
```

He probado varias cosas en el controlador, desde crear ahí unas variables para cada uno de los atributos mediante $_POST y mandárselos a la función mediante una cadena sql y hasta crear una función que recibe los parámetros, pero como la función me pide un objeto candidato, entiendo que hay que crear un new Candidato en el controlador. Si la función me pidiera los 5 atributos entendería como hacerlo pero al pedirme un objeto ya creado es lo que me choca. A ver si podéis ayudarme y puedo llegar a entender el funcionamiento, muchas gracias.

**Edit:** He conseguido que la función inserte, pero me inserta datos vacíos:

Función insert:

```
    public static function insertDatos($candidatoNuevo)
{

$sql5="INSERT INTO candidatos (dni, nombre, apellidos, sexo) 
 VALUES ('".$pdni."','".$pnombre."','".$papellidos."','".$psexo."')";
    return ($resultado=self::ejecutaConsultaAccion($sql5));

}
```

Grabar.php en el controlador:

```
    <?php
require_once("../model/base.php");
//si inserta
//header ("Location:index.php");
    
$pdni= $_POST["dni"];
$pnombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$papellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$psexo = $_POST["sexo"];
$pidiomas = $_POST["idiomas"];

$existe=ClaseBase::compruebaCandidato($pdni);
    if (!$existe)
    {
        $nuevoUser = new Candidato($pdni,$pnombre,$papellidos,$psexo,$pidiomas);
        //print_r($nuevoUser);
        ClaseBase::insertDatos($nuevoUser);

        echo "<p>El candidato ha sido insertado 
                 correctamente</p>";
    }
    else
        echo "<p>El dni .$pdni ya estaba registrado, inserta 
                 otro.</p>";


//si no
//require_once("../View/resultado.php")
?>
```

Haciendo un print_r de $nuevoUser:

```
Candidato Object ( [dni:protected] => 1111 [nombre:protected] => juan [apellidos:protected] => sanchez [sexo:protected] => m [idiomas:protected] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )
```

Y estos son los errores:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pdni in C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\base.php on line 104

Notice: Undefined variable: pnombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\base.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined variable: papellidos in C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\base.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined variable: psexo in C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\base.php on line 105
```

Por alguna razón que desconozco no le llegan las variables al modelo y me da error en la sentencia insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'Si la función me pidiera los 5 atributos entendería como hacerlo pero al pedirme un objeto ya creado es lo que me choca.'**

Los 5 atributos te los está pidiendo a la hora de crear el objeto candidato. La funcion __construct() es la encargada de eso. Se ejecuta cuando haces el "new Candidato".
Entonces si tu luego a la funcion insertDatos le pasas el objecto que has creado mediante "new Candidato" los parametros que le hayas pasado al __construct ya son propiedades del objeto

```
//Los datos que tu mencionas 
$candidato = new Candidato($pdni,$pnombre,$papellidos,$psexo,$pidiomas); //Aquí  los parametros se los pasas de la manera / nombre que los tengas en tu código, yo uso como ejemplo lo que pide el __construct

//En este punto ya tendrías un objeto $candidato el cual tiene 5 propiedades con los valores que tu has pasado mediante el construct. Ahora tienes que crear una instancia del modelo y llamar  a la funcion insertDatos pasandole el objeto
$modelo = new Modelo;
$modelo->insertDatos($candidato)
```

Comment: Pero esto: $candidato = new Candidato($pdni,$pnombre,$papellidos,$psexo,$pidiomas); tengo que hacerlo en el modelo?

Comment: En el controlador. En el controlador creas una instancia de la clase candidato de esa manera y luego una instancia del modelo. Y llamas a la funcion del modelo pasandole la instancia de la clase candidato.

Comment: Voy a actualizar la pregunta porque me han salido nuevos errores.

Comment: pude conseguirlo, en el insert tenia que poner $candidato->getDni() para que me cogiera el valor.